# DWmR pacakge in r

Tags: r

I am using  Rstudio 4.0.3 version and trying to install  DWmR package. I want to use SMOTE() function from this package.  but when trying to installing it is showing :

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘DMwR’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

Is there any solution by which I can install this package for this version? As far I have found this package was supported in earlier versions in R.

Comment: The package has been [removed from CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/package=DMwR) because the authors didn't make requested updates.

Comment: You can still access archive copies of the package. Follow the basic instructions included in the other question to install packages that have been removed from CRAN. (Though it may have been removed for an important reason, so use at your own risk.)

Comment: "Package ‘DMwR’ was removed from the CRAN repository." (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DMwR/index.html) - try downloading it from the archive and installing it from source: `download.file(url = "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/DMwR/DMwR_0.4.1.tar.gz", destfile = "test");
install.packages("test", repos = NULL, type = "source")`